# Android screen never turns off

Tags: android

I have a problem with my Android app, it doesn't seem to let the screen turn off ever. What could be the cause for it? isn't the screen supposed to turn off depending on the user's settings?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would normally say 'post some code', but I'm not sure that would be useful. However, could you post some code which may be a culprit? Do you have the setting set that relates to development and the screen when plugged in?

Comment: Maybe you have the option "stay awake" in settings->applications->development enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure none of your views uses [android:keepScreenOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3akeepScreenOn)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean when it's connected to your dev PC via USB, then perhaps you can check whether Settings/Applications/Development/Stay Awake is set?